# Playing a sound file at very high frequency in Python/Java

Tags: java, python, audio

I'm interested in simulating the sound of a petrol engine. I want to use the sound of a single piston compression and play it at high frequency to see what it would sound like. Python seems to stop working properly at about 50 revs/s. I need at least double that.

How can I achieve this with Python or Java?

My current code just uses winsound (using Python 3):

```
import winsound, time

revs = int(input('Enter revs: '))

timeDiff = 1.0/revs
print(timeDiff)

for i in range(0,100):
    winsound.PlaySound('exp3.wav', 3)
    time.sleep(timeDiff)
```

I know this isn't the best way to do engine sounds and samples with pitch shifting etc. may be more realistic, but this is for personal interest.

Comment: Hm,  how do I run this on linux? This seems to use a windows specific API.

Comment: Yes, winsound is a built-in module for running sounds on Windows

Comment: Why do you have a '3' on your call to PlaySound?

Comment: Oh I was just playing around with that parameter, I actually have no idea what the different values mean. With a 0, the sounds play sequentially and don't overlap while a 1 value makes them overlap.

Comment: Here have a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html

Comment: And I suspect that this is a problem with windows’ API itself… but again, since I can’t run this, I don’t know for sure.

Comment: One thing to consider:  Much of the sound of an engine is the sound that reverberates inside the exhaust system after each opening of an exhaust port.  The reverberations may last longer than the interval between exhaust port openings.  In other words, you may have to overlap them.